# Proposition 5.4. Chapter 0 - Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I think I have some issues with the notation used in the proposition below

> Let $X, Y$ be differentiable vector fields on a manifold $M$, let $p \in M$, and let $\varphi_t$ be the local flow of $X$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ Then
>   $$
> [X,Y](p) = \lim_{t\to 0} [Y - d\varphi_t Y](\varphi_t(p))
> $$

More specifically there's a limit at some point of the proof:

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(Yf)(\varphi_t(p)) - (Yf)(p)}{t} = (X(Yf))(p)
$$

which is the bit I don't quite get...

Could you help?

**Update**:

I was just reading again through this part, the following statement might actually help to understand the limit in my question

> Let $X$ be a differentiable vector field on a differentiable manifold $M$, and let $p \in M$. Then there exist a neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $p$, an interval $(-\delta,\delta)$, $\delta > 0$ and a differentiable mapping $\varphi : (-\delta,\delta) \times U \to M$ such that the curve $t \to \varphi(t,q)$, $t \in (-\delta,\delta)$, $q \in U$ is the unique curve which satisfies
>   $$
> \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = X(\varphi(t,q))
> $$
>   and $\varphi(0,q) = q$. A curve $\alpha:(-\delta,\delta) \to M$ which satisfies the condition $\alpha'(t) = X(\alpha(t))$ is called a trajectory of the field $X$ that passes through $q$ for $t = 0$

It is not explained exactly what does it mean that $\varphi(t,q)$ is differentiable, but given the definition I'd say that if we fix $q \in M$ then the restriction $\alpha_q(t)$ is curve on the manifold $M$, therefore I'd say that differentiable in this context would mean that the $\alpha'_q(0) \in T_q M$ exists, and this means

$$
\alpha'_q(0)f = \left. \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \alpha_q) \right|_{t=0} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (f \circ \varphi(\cdot,q)) \right|_{t=0}
$$

exists, here $f$ is a differentiable function defined on the manifold $M$.
Now if $Y$ is a differentiable vector field, which can be seen as an operator, instead of using $f$ I can use $Yf$, therefore I end up with

$$
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left((Yf) \circ \varphi(\cdot,q) \right) \right|_{t=0} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(Yf)(\varphi_t(p)) - (Yf)(p)}{t}
$$

But it must be

$$
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (Yf) = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left((Yf) \circ \varphi(\cdot,q) \right) \right|_{t=0}
$$

By definition of tangent vector, since $\varphi$ is a local flow for $X$ (in the proposition) we can write

$$
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (Yf) = X(Yf)(\varphi_t(q))
$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: You can find this shown explicitly on page 225 of Tu's "Intro to Manifolds."

Comment: It's in the statement of the proposition, what do you mean? Does my question lack of details?

Comment: @cmk I don't have that book...

Comment: You might want to study a basic book on differentiable manifolds before jumping into doCarmo's book on Riemannian Geometry. Lee, Spivak volume 1, Boothby, Tu .... any number of reasonable books to get a good background.

Comment: Do you mean differential geometry?

Comment: Makes sense to me. However, in the line above where he says 
$$
((d\varphi_t Y)f)(\varphi_t(p)) = (Y(f \circ \varphi_t))(p),
$$
where did the $d \varphi_t$ go?

Comment: That's the definition because of the definition of the differential map, or push forward. If $\varphi_t : U \subset M \to M$ and $Y \in T_p M$ then $d \varphi_t Y \in T_{\varphi_t(p)} M$. Which means that a tangent vector $Y_p$ (right handside) is mapped into $(d\varphi_t Y)_{\varphi_t(p)}$ (left handside) through the flow $\varphi_t$. I like doCarmo's book but honestly is notation si horrible... I had to follow the advice of reading through another book to get sufficient background.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you have displayed is wrong. What is correct is that
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(Yf)(\phi_t(p)) - (Yf)(p)}t = X_p(Yf) = (X(Yf))(p).$$
(This follows because the curve $\phi_t(p)$ is a curve through $p$ with tangent vector $X_p$ at $p$.)

Comment: Can you please explain how do you compute the limit? I don't know if it is wrong what I've copied from the book, also the notation you're using isn't the same as the one used by Do Carmo.

Comment: You don't have to compute, this is the definition of the directional derivative of $Yf$ in the direction of $X$ at $p$.

Comment: I don't see any definition of directional derivative, there's the statement: *The bracket $[X,Y]$ can also be interpreted as a derivation of $Y$ along the "trajectoris" of $X$. To describe this interpretation we need some preliminary ideas on differential equations... The interpretation of the bracket $[X,Y]$ given above is contained in the following proposition*. The proposition is the one in my question, there's no definition of directional derivative, there's the interpretation given by that proposition.

Comment: Worth to mention the differential equation commented is $$ \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = X(\varphi(t,q))$$. It is commented under which hypothesis such equation has solution, if such equation is used somehow then I don't really know.

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look to my update and see if it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi,\ \psi$ are local flows of vector fields $X,\ Y$, i.e.
$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \phi(t,x)=X_{\phi(t,x)}$, then
$$ L_XY (f)(p)= \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0}\
 (\phi(-t)_\ast Y_{\phi(t) }
)(f) $$ where $f$ is a function around a point $p$.